# Why does this Python code (compositing a list extension with a map of itself) make my system freeze up?

Tags: python, lambda, freeze

When I run

```
a = ['a']
a.extend(map(lambda x: 'b' + x, a))
```

it locks my system up until I can do a Ctrl+C if I run it as a Python script from the shell, and running it from the interpreter made me have to hard shutdown my laptop.

However,

```
a = ['a']
a.extend(list(map(lambda x: 'b' + x, a)))
```

works fine and gives the expected result.

Why does this happen?

At first, I thought it might be because I was trying to extend `a` with a map function that ran on `a` itself, so I wrote:

```
a = ['a']
tmp = map(lambda x: 'b' + x, a)
a.extend(tmp)
```

However, that also froze up.

Similarly, this seems to work fine:

```
a = ['a']
tmp = list(map(lambda x: 'b' + x, a))
a.extend(tmp)
```

Why is this happening?

I'm doing this on **Python 3.4.3**.

Comment: This works fine in python 2.7.* so my guess would be that the problem is related to the fact that `map` function returns a `map object` in python 3 (as opposed to a list in python 2).

Comment: It works fine for me both on 3.4.3 as well as on 2.7.9

Comment: Hum.  My intuition is the same as your original one---this smells of a list mutability problem.  And the fact that both versions work when wrapped in the list() (which makes a copy of the list) is a big clue for that.  My guess is that both versions without the list code are mutating the original list (with the 2nd version doing it via a pointer) and the map is continuing to extend them, leading to infinite loop.  However, the consequences of list mutability and the bizarre stuff Python does with pointers are way above my pay grade, so this may be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3, an iterator will be generated from `map()` function.

When seeing `a.extend()` function, python will find that you want to extend list `a` with an iterator related to `a` and automatically help you to do the iterating.

And here the iteration begins.

Firstly, it's a `'a'` in a. The iterator inside `map()` function gives `'a'`, a `'ba'` is generated from your `lambda` expression and get appended into list `a`. `a` becomes `['a', 'ba']` now.

Then, the iterator inside `map()` function finds that iterating over `a` is not giving `StopIteration` due to `a`'s new pal `'ba'`'s comming. So the iterator inside `map()` function gives `'ba'` for `lambda` to process. A `'bba'` is generated here and get pushed into `a`.

That's how `a`'s infinite propagation works.

The following code may help:

```
a = ['a']
import time
a.extend(map(lambda x: ('b' + x, print(x), time.sleep(1))[0], a))
```

And it should be trivial to understand why your using of `list()` to transform the iterator into a static list don't trigger this.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in Python 3.x `map()` function returns an iterator, which uses the reference of the list passed to it as the second parameter. So as you are iterating over the map iterator, you are also extending the list, and this keeps on going indefinitely , hence you either get `MemoryError` or you end up with an infinite loop.

Example to show this behavior -

```
>>> m = map(lambda x: a.extend(x), a)
>>> m
<map object at 0x021E0E70>
>>> for i,x in enumerate(m):
...     print("Hello")
...
Hello
Hello
.... # lots of Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
MemoryError
```

So when you do - `a.extend(map(lambda x: 'b' + x, a))` . You are doing something similar to -

```
a = ['a']
for x in a:
    a.extend('b'+x)
```

If you try the above code, you will still get the `MemoryError` or the infinite loop.

When you do -

```
a.extend(list(map(lambda x: 'b' + x, a)))
```

You are using up the iterator by converting it into a list, before you are extending the list `a` , hence it does not end up in an infinite loop. In this case you are doing something similar to-

```
a = ['a']
templist = []
for x in a:
    templist.extend('b' + x)
a.extend(templist)
```

So that is why you do not get the error. Please note above code may not be how python internally runs `map` , its just something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think Python's object management mechanism is different from C/C++, see this:

```
a = ['a']
```

`for x in a:
    a.append('b')`

if you type in your Python command line, you will encounter a infinite loop, and after you input CTRL+C, and

```
>>> a
```

you will get a long list that contains 'a' and 'b', and I think in for loop, the a and the a of a.append('b') are the same object and in the same memory.
That's what i think.

Comment: So, when the a list are updating and `for x in a` becomes longer and longer

Comment: `a.append('b')` makes `a` larger and larger, and when the next loop comes the `a` in `for x in a:` are different from the last loop, cause it appended a 'b'. So that's a infinite loop